# vlc beta for android intent not working

Tags: video, android-intent, video-streaming, vlc, m3u

Hi i have created an android app that uses vlc to play live streams but i am having a problem

i am using vlc beta neon to play the streams from my app but i have a problem

i am using androids intent to to open a .m3u playlist to play

the codes i am using for my intent are

```
    package : org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon
    activity : org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity
    data type : video/*
    video url : http://uk-iptv.co.uk/istream/rob/69314.m3u
```

now this works and it opens vlc perfect but then my problem starts wen it loads vlc it gets stuck on a screen with a spinning cone saying please wait with a play button behind it and the stream never starts to play no matter how long i leave it

i know the playlist is ok because if i open the vlc app my self and play the stream it opens in a second the problem only seems to be wen i open the stream threw intent :/

i tried using mx player but even tho it says it supports m3u and live streams that app just says it cant play the video :/

could anyone help i have no idea whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Action "view" instead of the possibly default "main" seems to be the thing you're missing.

```
  'action':   'view',
  'package':  'org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon',
  'class':    'org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity',
  'uri':      urllib.quote(url),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get this out on the web. If you're looking to use the command line activity manager to broadcast an intent, you can use this:

```
am start "<URI>;type=<MIMETYPE>;component=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon/.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity;end"
```